# How to find the end address of a function in a C prog?

Tags: c

Start address can be obtained from the function name, how to find the end address of a function? 
I have been asked this question in interview:

Consider the function f() which i wrote has crossed the text section and started over writing the adjacent section (data section). How can i handle this situation? Also he added that i should handle it through C code. I should not see the symbol map file and get the address.

Comment: There is no standard way. You might try taking the address of the next function in the file, then subtracting -- but there's no guarantee it'll work. For example, the linker might sort functions into alphabetical order, so that might include space for other functions, or it might give a negative size.

Comment: You have to specify architecture and ABI or you won't get useful answers.

Comment: "I have been asked this question in interview" I suspect that you have misunderstood the question, and they were asking how to tell if you began accidentally executing data. The answer would be "Data Execution Prevention" otherwise known a a hardware feature for flagging memory as not to be executed.

Comment: A function cannot "cross the text section" because of the way code is generated and linked, function code (and hence its end address) always lies in the text segment. You can jump outside the text segment by following a bad pointer or if your compiler is buggy and produced wrong assembly that doesn't return correctly or there is a corruption of the return address in the stack but that has nothing to do with the end address of your function. Besides function can get inlined if the compiler decides so - what is the end address then?

Answer (score 7):

With GCC, you can take the address of a label, with the `&&` operator (yes - `&&`, not `&`).
This can be used as follows:

```
void f(void) {
    printf("Start %p End %p\n", f, &&f_end);
    f_end: return;
}
```

This won't give you exactly the end, because there's some epilogue code after the label, but I think it's good enough for an interview answer.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not guarantee that there is such a thing as then end address of a function.

In practice, functions are not necessarily a single continuous piece of memory, but can overlap, or be fragmented across several pieces by code optimisers.

For that reason there is no way to find this out at runtime.

Furthermore, there is no guarantee that the "start address" you get from GetProcAddress or by taking the address of the function (for a function pointer) bears any relation to where the code actually is.

All a function pointer guarantees is that if you call through the address the function will be executed. It does not guarantee that the code actually resides there. It may just be the address of a thunk, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't using the language itself, C doesn't expose a concept of "size" for functions.

What you might be able to do is inspect your program's binary file, and parse the symbol tables and so on.

Comment: Have you any library to recommend to help in the parsing of the symbol table ? Strangely I am not able to find a "read elf library" but only a command line tool

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler can probably produce an assembly listing file and your linker can probably produce a map file.  These would let you see how long a particular function is manually.  Not sure if you need to determine the size from within the C program itself.